# How to make a series of shapes half the size?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a scene with a bunch of shapes, drawn like this:

```
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-0.7f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.7f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.4f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.4f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
```

How do I make all of the shapes half as small, without individually going through and changing each coordinate?

Answer (score 3):

The question is a little bit ambiguous.  You asked to make the quads be half their original size, but you didn't stipulate where they should be once their size is changed.  The standard way would be to apply a scaling factor:

```
glPushMatrix();
glScaled(.5,.5,.5);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(-0.7f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.7f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.4f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.4f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
glEnd();

...
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
...
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

This will scale everything after the `glScale` call until the `glPopMatrix()`.  Consequently, the quads will be half the size, but will also be half the distance from the origin (not a problem here where it's centered at the origin).  If you want to apply the scaling factor to the quads, but not to their location, you'd probably need something like this:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(xx,yy,zz);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3d( ww*ss, hh*ss,0);
glVertex3d(-ww*ss, hh*ss,0);
glVertex3d(-ww*ss,-hh*ss,0);
glVertex3d( ww*ss,-hh*ss,0);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

Then you would just set `ss` to your desired value and use `xx,yy,zz` to place the quad where you want it.  Of course it's a bit silly to do things just this way, at very least, you should multiply the values once each and remember them, but you get the idea.

Comment: In your second example, you can translate the shape to its origin, scale and then translate back to avoid modifying the coordinates.

Comment: @geofftnz Good point.  Since the quad is deliberately centered around the origin, the scale factor should probably just be applied as a glScale() right before the quad is drawn.